# what sholud i use to get the value from the fields userid and password in php? I get an empty string with given code

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have to file main.html(main file) and login.html(contetns only form without html document means body and html tags) and use the .load() method of jquery to load the form from login.html to the main.html and submit to the login.php. And when i try to fetch the value of the input field in php it just give a empty string or say nothing. I don't want to use this method only. So is it wrong or not possible or is there any other php method which is able to fetch these fields.

main.html

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Media</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">   </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0    /additional-methods.min.js"></script-->

        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav-placeholder" name="nav-placeholder"></div>
        <div id="body" name="body">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<div id="loginPage">
    <br><h1>My Media</h1><br><br><br>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" action="login.php">
        UserId:<br><input id="userid" name="userid" type="text" required><br>
        Password:<br><input id="password" name="password" type="password" required><br>
        <input id="Login" name="Login" type="submit" value="login">
    </form> 
</div>
```

jquery.js

```
$(function(){
    var page="home";
                $("#nav-placeholder").load("menu.html");    
                $("#body").load("home.html")

    $("body").on("click","#home",function(){
        if(page!="home"){
        $("#body").empty();//after("<h3><u>Some appended text.</u></h3>");
        $("#body").load("home.html");
        page="home";}
    }); 

    $("body").on("click","#help",function(){
    if(page!="help"){
        $("#body").empty();//after("<h3><u>Some appended text.</u></h3>");
        $("#body").load("help.html");
        page="help";}
    }); 

    $("body").on("click","#login",function(){
        if(page!="login"){
        $("#body").empty();//after("<h3><u>Some appended text.</u></h3>");
        $("#body").load("login.html");
        page="login";}
    }); 

    $("body").on("click","#register",function(){
        if(page!="register"){
        $("#body").empty();//after("<h3><u>Some appended text.</u></h3>");
        $("#body").load("register.html");
        login="register";}
    });

    $("body").on("click","#about",function(){
        if(page!="home"){
        $("#body").empty();//after("<h3><u>Some appended text.</u></h3>");
        $("#body").load("about.html");
        page="about";}  
    });

    $("body").on("click","#bottom",function(){
        if(page!="home"){
        $("#body").empty();//after("<h3><u>Some appended text.</u></h3>");
        $("#body").focus("#contacts");
        page="about";}  
    });

});
```

login.php

```
<?php

$usrname = $_POST["userid"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];

echo $usrname."--".$pass;
?>
```

what should a use?

Comment: What does the `validate()` function ?

Comment: You can see what happens with [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools). Use them!

Comment: it suppose to validates the fields entered but i just remove if from .js for sipliscity here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ashitosh Kamble

You should send the form values in a json format using an ajax call when the user clicks on login.

```
var userid = $('#userid').val();
var password = $('#password').val();

var data = {
  "user_id":userid,
  "homeTown": password
}

$("#login").click(function(event){
       $.ajax( {
                  url:'login.php',
                  type:'post',
                  success:function(data) {
                     // Allow Login
                  }
               });
            });
```

Hope it works!!

Comment: @AshitoshKamble Good to hear that, If you don't mind, please upvote the answer. Thanks.